# error LNK2005 when c++ lambdas used with /Yu flag in vs2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11, precompiled

I have the following function in one of my utility header files.

```
template<typename T>
static void rtrim(std::basic_string<T, std::char_traits<T>, std::allocator<T>> &t) 
{ 
      t.erase(find_if(t.rbegin(), t.rend(), 
              [](T& c)->bool{ return !isspace(c); }).base(), t.end());
}
```

I am building the code with Visual Studio 2012 with pre-compiled headers on (/Yu).  The build fails with the following error.

> 1>stdafx.obj : error LNK2005: "public: void __cdecl
>   ::operator()(class
>   std::basic_string,class
>   std::allocator > const &)const "
>   (??R@@QEBAXAEBV?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@Z)
>   already defined in

If I remove `/Yu` flag, it builds fine.  Does it mean lambdas cannot be used with precompiled headers?  Is there a work around?

Comment: Instead of `static void rtrim(...)` try `inline void rtrim(...)`. Does that fix the problem?

Comment: Another option is to get rid of the lambda - `find_if(t.rbegin(), t.rend(), ::isspace)`

Comment: Inlining did not work.  My code is full of templates.  I want to simplify my template code with c++ lamdas.  This is the simple example i am trying.  My code was not using lamdas before and it looked exactly like you said.

Comment: I noticed that it only happens when native c++11 libraries are linked to managed c++ application.  I mean, build errors appear in managed c++ application.

Comment: @Praetorian: template functions are already `inline` --well, not strictly speaking, but in reality the properties that `inline` confers to a function are already properties of the function template.

Comment: @David I think I know what you're saying; it's the whole *marked as weak symbol, linker picks one* thing. sreeram: I tried creating a new project using precompiled headers, and containing 2 cpp files. I included `<string>` and `<algorithm>` in stdafx.h along with the function you have. I then called it in both cpp files, but it doesn't result in any such error.